# Communicating between a BeagleBone Black and a servo controller

Tags: motor, microcontroller

I am a complete newbie and recently joined a robot team at my school in order to gain some experience. I have been assigned a task of driving a servo using a Pololu Mini Maestro USB Servo Controller. I am using the BeagleBone Black (BBB) with the Python adafruit library. How do I make the BBB communicate with the Servo Controller? If you guys could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate that. Right now, I don't even know where to start. Not sure if it matters, but this is the servo I am using: https://www.pololu.com/product/1053

Answer (score 1):

The beagle bone black is just a linux computer without the monitor. Look at the user guide (https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J40). It shows examples of writing software to interface with the servo controller.